# Issue with open Google Map URL in WebView?

Tags: android, titanium

I am developing an Application in Titanium Studio for Android.
I want to use Google MAP URL for Displaying Google MAP in WebView. But this is not working. (This is working fine in iOS and Web Browser). But I want to open in WebView.

Please, Help me!!!
Any suggestion is appreciated

Thanks in Advance...!!!

```
var web = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    height : "50%",
    width :"100%",
    url : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/25.611,85.144/23.022505,72.571362",
    // url : "https://www.google.com",
    top :0,
});
```

Comment: What's "not working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the property `borderRadius:1`

Comment: How did this fix the issue?

Comment: Such a bs answer.. if your gonna answer your own questions, at least explain how the answer is at all relevant to your question.. This does not work when under android to fix the problem.

Comment: @NinjaKC 
var web = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    height : "50%",
    width :"100%",
    url : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/25.611,85.144/23.022505,72.571362",
    // url : "https://www.google.com",
    top :0,
borderRadius:1
}); 
This is working for, show your code, Then let me check where then exact problem.